# MKPolygon with overlapping interiorPolygons displays incorrectly due to even-odd fill rule

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I am trying to have a "fog of war" type effect for a map.

I am using the MKPolygon class (the greyed out area) with an array of interiorPolygons to display the cutout sections.

```
var points = [MKMapPointMake(centerPoint.x - (accuracy * squareOffset), centerPoint.y - (accuracy * squareOffset)),
            MKMapPointMake(centerPoint.x + (accuracy * squareOffset), centerPoint.y - (accuracy * squareOffset)),
            MKMapPointMake(centerPoint.x + (accuracy * squareOffset), centerPoint.y + (accuracy * squareOffset)),
            MKMapPointMake(centerPoint.x - (accuracy * squareOffset), centerPoint.y + (accuracy * squareOffset))]

var polygon = MKPolygon(points: &points, count: 4, interiorPolygons: cutouts)
```

Right now, my results look like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hk94jmybc4iqti0/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-06%20at%209.31.29%20PM.png

The problem is that the overlapping MKPolgyons in interiorPolygons default back to the original grey color.

The correct behavior should be (which I have done imperfectly in paint to illustrate):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/izc8umm28t4ggf9/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-06%20at%209.07.27%20PM.png

My first question: How do you set the overlapping color of interiorPolygons to be transparent?

Second Question: Is there a way to use MKCircle instead of MKPolygons for interiorPolygons? I think the effect would look much better as circles instead of Rectangles.

**EDIT:** 
I dug more into the docs and found this:

"When creating a polygon, you can mask out portions of the polygon by specifying one or more interior polygons. For the polygons you specify, this class uses the even-odd fill rule to determine the final occupied area. When applied to overlapping polygons, this rule can cause specific regions to be masked out (and thereby removed) from the total occupied area. For more information about how fill rules are applied to paths, see Paths in Quartz 2D Programming Guide."

This led me to the docs that say:

CGContextFillPath
Fills the current path using the nonzero winding number rule.

I need to use the nonzero winding number rule instead of even odd, but I'm not 100% sure how to do that.

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm looking for the same solution you needed.

Comment: No I did not figure this out

Comment: Did anyone of you figure this out? @djschwartz and Jontonsoup